# How to count a char*?

Tags: c, char

I am trying to count a char*, but my looping never stop until it reach the last part of memory allocation...?

Here's what I mean:

```
char* text1 = "Hello Guys!";
char* text2 = "i dont know why";
char* text3 = "Hello World";

int counter = 0;
for(char* temp = text1;temp != '\0';)
{
   ++temp; ++counter;
}
//then i printed Counter
```

But for some reason, my counter shows 106506.

When I debug those, after temp shown "!" and then it goes to "" it keeps going. :(

and after a few step, my char* (temp) reach the text2 memory, and text3 memory. "I don't know why" and "Hello World" are counted as well.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `p`?

Comment: `temp`? `p`? Which one do you use? Or do you use both?

Comment: `for(char* temp = text1;p != '\0';)` `p` is never changed in your for loop!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `p` may be changed if it is assigned to memory mapped I/O, for example. We cannot tell it from the current posted code.

Comment: @MikeCAT I seriously doubt that's in question actually.

Comment: anyway, i even tried using
temp != ""
temp  != (char)0
temp  != NULL
but still has the same result

Comment: @SandioDwikoMustika What's `p` dude, and where it is changed??

Comment: sorry guys. typo. it actually is "temp"

Comment: Do note that `char* text1 = "Hello Guys!";` is not standard C++.  You should use `const char* text1 = "Hello Guys!";` or `char text1[] = "Hello Guys!";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`temp` is a pointer and it won't be equal to `'\0'`, which is 0, in the loop.

To access to the character pointed at by that, use `*temp`.

Comment: ahhh. the value. now i know why. thank you sir. :)

Comment: It certainly is not intended, but strictly speaking it is correct (from C standard, 6.3.2.3p3): "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant. ..." and 6.5.9p5 (equality operators): "Otherwise, at least one operand is a pointer. If one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant, the null pointer constant is converted to the type of the pointer."

Comment: @Olaf I meant the pointer won't compare equal to 0 during the iteration before invoking undefined behavior by going out-of-range.

Comment: @MikeCAT: That's why I wrote "It certainly is not intended" - Sorry if that was not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not assign string literal to `char *` even if compiler allows that for compatibility, second you do not need additional pointer:

```
const char* text1 = "Hello Guys!";

int counter = 0;
for( ; text1[counter]; ++counter );
```

but better use `strlen()`:

```
int counter = strlen( text1 );
```